# Botão não aparece

Tags: php, html, css

```css
  
a {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #007bff;
padding: 10px;
display: block;
width: 250px;
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-text-decoration-skip: objects;
 }
 a:hover{
  background-color: #0f58a7;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
 }
```

```html
 <a href='teste.com'><i class='fas fa-arrow-right'></i> PROSSEGUIR</a>
```

Tenho esse botão, que deveria aparecer assim: http://prntscr.com/n54rd9
Mas por algum motivo que eu não consegui identificar, o botão não aparece para algumas pessoas que acessam a pagina. Haveria algo que possa ser feito para identificar o motivo disso acontecer? Em todos os navegador das pessoas que tem esse problema, nunca aparece...então não deve ser o navegador bloqueando algo.

Comment: 1º - Cadê o código de estilo CSS? Coloque o código CSS que formata o botão para que possamos ver. 2º - O botão não aparece para algumas pessoas ou aparece para você e para os outros não?

Comment: Acabei de adicionar o CSS ao post. Sobre a segunda pargunta, ele aparece para mim e diversas outras pessoas, cerca de 90%, mas para algumas pessoas ele não aparece de forma alguma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que provavelmente etá acontecendo é que vc está usando a versão SVG do FontAwesome. O FontAwesome tem uma versão que usa webfonte e uma versão mais nova que usa SVG. Porém se o browser do usuário não der suporte ao SVG e a forma como os métodos do JS do framework trabalha a fonte não aparece... Como vc pode ver na imagem abaixo retirada do site oficial: https://fontawesome.com/start

A versão em webfont é: https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css

A versão em SVG é: https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/js/all.js

Confirme se vc está usando a versão .JS ou .CSS

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Lista de suporte dos Browsers**
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/other-topics/browser-support

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Estou usando esta versão: http://prntscr.com/n58h9g (.css)
Nesta versão: v5.0.12
E a que você mandou ja é a 5.8.1. Será que atualizando para essa 5.8.1 ja resolve?

Comment: @RafaelMacedo infelizmente acho que não vai resolver, apesar de eu recomendar sim que vc atualiza para versão mais nova! Essa atualização da v5.0 para v5.8, são alguns recursos extras e ajustes de alguns icones etc... Como vc já usa a versão .CSS do FW, não sei te dizer exatamente pq não aparece para alguns, além é claro da questão do suporte do Browser como falei e vc pode ver na imagem. Outro motivo menos provável é que essas pessoas por questão de segurança bloqueiam o acesso ao `href` de sites fora do domínio ou fora do *white list*...

Comment: Entendi, mas obrigado de qualquer forma.